# argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "STRSAFE_LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, string, strsafe

I have the following:

```
DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION dtzRecorder;
GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(&dtzRecorder);
```

I normally do the following to copy a new name:

```
StringCchCopy(dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName, 128, L"GMT Standard Time");
```

But now I need to do the following:

```
char tzKey[51];

std::string timezone("someTimeZOneName");
strncpy_s(MyStruct.tzKey, timezone.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);

StringCchCopy(dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName, 128, MyStruct.tzKey); <--Error
```

But I get the error:

**argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "STRSAFE_LPCWSTR"**

How can I copy this to dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName??

Comment: Try changing _`std::string timezone("someTimeZOneName");`_ to `std::wstring timezone("someTimeZOneName");`

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that `dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName` is a **wide** string (`wchar_t[]`), but `tzKey` is a **narrow** string (`char[]`).

The easiest way to solve it would be to use `wchar_t` for `tzKey`, too:

```
wchar_t tzKey[51];

std::wstring timezone(L"someTimeZOneName");
wcsncpy_s(MyStruct.tzKey, timezone.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);

StringCchCopy(dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName, 128, MyStruct.tzKey);
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I cannot change the tzKey string as it is used elsewhere.  I just need to convert the MyStruct.tzKey somehow to dtzRecorder.TimeZoneKeyName.

Comment: You can use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the string

Answer (score 1):

`LPSTR` is Microsoft for "Long Pointer to STRing" or `char *`, `LPWSTR` is Microsoft for "Long Pointer to Wide-c STring" or `wchar_t *`. Additionally `LPCSTR` and `LPCWSTR` refer to const variants.

The error you see comes from passing an `LPCSTR` (const character pointer) to a function expecting an `LPWSTR` (non-const unicode/wide character pointer).

Wide string constants are denoted with an `L` prefix (`L"wide"`), generally have the type `wchar_t*` and require a variant of `std::string` called `std::wstring`.

Which is the default for most Windows system calls is handled by a general project setting "Character Set", if it is "Unicode" then wide strings are required. Support for this is provided by `<tchar.h>` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx

```
#include <tchar.h>

// tchar doesn't help with std::string/std::wstring, so use this helper.
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define TSTRING std::wstring
#else
#define TSTRING std::string
#endif

// or as Matt points out
typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> TSTRING;

// Usage
TCHAR tzKey[51];  // will be char or wchar_t accordingly
TSTRING timezone(_T("timezonename")); // string or wstring accordingly
_tscncpy_s(tzKey, timezone.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
```

Alternatively you can just be explicit about using wides

```
wchar_t tzKey[51]; // note: this is not 51 bytes
std::wstring timezone(L"timezonename");
wscncpy_s(tzKey, timezone.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
```

As an aside, why not simply do this:

```
std::wstring timezone(L"tzname");
timezone.erase(50); // limit length
```

Why waste time copying the value when you could just insert a null-terminator at the limit?

Comment: You can use `typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> TSTRING;` instead of using an `#ifdef`.

Comment: The `C` in these typedefs means `const`. `LPSTR` is `char *`, `LPCSTR` is `const char *`, and `LPCWSTR` which OP has is `const wchar_t *`.